# Setting Conditions on InfoPath 2013 to swap between four Views

Tags: 2013, infopath, infopath-rules

I have four different Views/Sections of the form. When one view is filled in I want it to switch to the next when the form is opened again.

I've set up a Form Load Rule so that when a mandatory field is not Blank it'll switch to the next View. It works fine on one view but won't switch to the next. What am I doing wrong?

[image: Conditions]